# Easy software for : Multibody dynamics of rigid bodies?

Tags: dynamics, software

I am currently searching for an easy-to-use tool to understand/simulate multibody dynamics of rigid bodys.

I have no engineering or mechanics background (I am from IT) and I feel that I cannot imagine in my head how mechanics are behaving if they are moved in this or that direction.
To get a better understanding it would help me a lot to have some software where I could click the bodies and move them with the cursor in this or that direction and watch how they are behaving.

[image]
[image]

Do you have any suggestion of such a software? I googled already for some hours, but all I found are very complex 3D simulation software-solutions.
I don't care about exact dimensions or weights or gravity or anything. 2D is also totally fine for me. All I need is something where I can draw lines (bodies) and connect them with other lines and then afterwards move them.

Any help is very appreciated!

BR, mezorian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find that [SolveSpace](https://solvespace.com/index.pl) (multi-platform, free) will do as you require. For your purposes, it's not particularly difficult to learn.

The site also has a [link to a tutorial](https://solvespace.com/linkage.pl) which directly addresses multi-bar linkages. The image below is directly from the tutorial page and is certainly more complex than you present, but it representative of the capabilities of the program.

[image: multi-bar linkage]

Additionally, the program allows movement of the linkages and tracing of a specific point if required.

Eric Buijs has a collection of tutorial videos on peertube, one specifically oriented to [multi-bar linkages](https://peertube.linuxrocks.online/w/3nq8n9wMLDsvFHSvCUEz83). The linked video is more than 21 minutes long and clearly narrated. Movement is shown at about the ten minute point in the video.

Comment: Hi @fred-dot-u , thanks a lot for your answer! 
I think your suggestion looks pretty much like what I was searching for!
And it even seems to run on linux :) Super cool!